# GET not able to handle Redirect in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, post, redirect, get

So, I have this POST method in NodeJS that handles the login authentication

```
// Login logic
app.post("/home", function(req, res){
    Item.findOne({EmailID: req.body.emailAddress}, function (err, docs) {
     
        if(req.body.emailAddress === docs.EmailID && hash(req.body.password, docs.Salt) === docs.Password) {
          currentUser = docs.FirstName;
          console.log("Damn");
          res.redirect("dashboard.html");
 
  }

});
});
```

I can see in the console that "Damn" is printed, but for some reason, the redirect doesn't go to the following GET "dashboard.html" method as it is supposed to go but rather goes to the 404 error function

```
app.get("/dashboard.html", (req, res)=>{
  console.log("here we go again");
    
    Activity.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
    res.render("home", {newListItems: foundItems});
  });
});
```

and instead goes to the following 404 function. "here we go again" doesn't print on the console. Any idea on how to make the redirect go to the get function?

```
app.get("/*", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/404.html")
});
```

This is my HTML

```
  <form class="" action="/home" method="post">
        <div class="">
        <img class ="tent-image"src="assets/images/tent.png" alt width="90" height="72">
        <h4 class="company">PASTIME</h4>
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal"> Sign in</h1>
        <h4 class="h3 fw-normal" style="color: <%= inputcolor %>"> <%= FirstLine %><br /> <%= SecondLine%> </h4>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="virtually-hidden"></label>
        <input id="inputEmail" name="emailID" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="visually-hidden">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="passWORD" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2021 Pastime</p>

      </form>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

try by using

res.redirect("/dashboard.html");